# How to concatonate string in iteration loop

Tags: javascript, iteration

My output is

> 1
>   1
>   2
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   …

The output I am looking for is

> 1
>   1 2
>   1 2 3
>   1 2 3 4
>   1 2 3 4 5

```js
var x,y;
for(x=1; x <= 5; x++){
    for (y=1; y <= x; y++) {
        console.log(y)
    }
}
```

Comment: create a variable outside the loop: `var str = ""`, then inside loop just do: `str += valueYouWantToConcatenate`. Then log it after the loops

Comment: I don't see much difference from the your actual output and expected output, can you elaborate?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia,the question title: "How to **concatenate** string in iteration loop"

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop with a part variable and one for the full string.

Then you need to add a space only if the string is not empty and add in each loop the new value and the actual part to the full string.

```js
var i,
    part = '',
    full = '';
    
for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    part += (part && ' ') + i;
    full += (full && ' ') + part;
}

console.log(full);
```

Comment: Thats quite elegant (not sure if its more efficient, as string concatenation time also grows ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
var x,y,z='';
for(x=1; x <= 5; x++){
    for (y=1; y <= x; y++) {
        z = z + y + ' ';
    }
}
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```js
var x, y, concatenatedString = '';

for(x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    for (y=1; y <= x; y++) {
        concatenatedString += `${y} `
    }
}
console.log(concatenatedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet below:

```js
var str = ''

for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  for (let j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
    str += `${j} `
  }
}

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are console logging each time which puts it on a new line. 
It's a better idea to store numbers in an array and then print out one by one.

```
var x, y, myArray[];
for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
  for (y = 1; y <= x; y++) {
    myString += y.toString() + " ";
  }
}
console.log(myString);
```

You could also place numbers in an array and output one by one.